# Custom Keyboard, Moving from one view to another

Tags: java, android, keyboard

when the default android keyboard shows up it looks like that :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvBIG.png)

and when we click on "123Sym" it becomes like that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4jlk.png)

How can i do that with the keyboard I created, I mean Moving from one view to another.

Here my java Class:

```
public class EDMTKeyboard extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

private KeyboardView kv;
private Keyboard keyboard;

private  boolean isCaps = false;

@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {
    kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard,null);
    keyboard = new Keyboard(this,R.xml.qwerty);
    kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    return kv;
}

@Override
public void onPress(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onRelease(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onKey(int i, int[] ints) {

    InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
    playClick(i);
    switch (i)
    {
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
            ic.deleteSurroundingText(1,0);
        break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
            isCaps = !isCaps;
            keyboard.setShifted(isCaps);
            kv.invalidateAllKeys();
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
            //ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
            break;
            default:
                char code = (char)i;
                if(Character.isLetter(code) && isCaps)
                    code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
                ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code),1);
    }

}

private void playClick(int i) {

    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    switch(i)
    {
        case 32:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
        case 10:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE);
            break;
        default: am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD);
    }
}

@Override
public void onText(CharSequence charSequence) {

}

@Override
public void swipeLeft() {

}

@Override
public void swipeRight() {

}

@Override
public void swipeDown() {

}

@Override
public void swipeUp() {

}
```

I want when i press on a key the keyboard shows the symbols

Comment: Have you tried calling kv.setKeyboard and passing it a keyboard from the symbols xml file?  That should work.  Of course a lot depends on what you're trying to do, if you're going to do anything non trivial you're probably better off not using KeyboardView at all, its extremely limiting.

Comment: I tried it but when when the keyboard disappears and shows up again, it shows the Symbols view